# configure browser url autocompletion

Tags: browser, autocomplete

My company's intranet has url "http://jira/J######" for Jira case J######, for example, case J123456's url is actually http://jira/J123456.

Is it possible to configure chrome or IE or any browser's url autocompletion, such that when I paste J123456 in the url and enter, it will automatically complete it as http://jira/J123456 and go there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need a browser plugin for this. Also, as a personal note, drop IE support. Especially for Jira. Either use Edge2 (based on Chromium), Chrome or FF.

For example [Redirector for FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/ro/firefox/addon/redirector/). According to the description, it seems close to what you want, else, you'll need to develop your own plug-ins depending on the browser.